# TV series about a boy and a ghost girl who was abused?

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid, I remember watching a TV series about a boy, who could see ghosts through his video camera. He became friends with one of the ghosts, a little girl, and there was a scene of both of them on a carousel together I think? The little girl's caregiver/mother abused her, and I think the boy and his family or friends were trying to find ways to put the little girl ghost to rest.
I've desperately tried finding this but haven't found anything close :(.

edit; 
It was a british childrens tv show, live action, and I watched it around 2004 I imagine? it was set in a modern era but the the girl ghost was from an older era, maybe victorian. i really cant remember anything else than that though

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVcolCQBKyc

Comment: If you have a look at "[How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)" you might find that the checklists help you to remember additional details about this TV show.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. We also don't know when you were a kid; please provide a year range instead of 'when I was a kid'. I hope you decide to stick around!

Comment: When were you a kid? Was the show new when you were a child? What kind of video camera was it? What was the little girl's name? How was she abused? How did she die? What was the boy's name? Was the boy modern and the ghost girl from an earlier time period? What other ghosts did he see? Was this show animated or live-action? Was the boy Caucasian? Was the ghost girl Caucasian? Could he only see her through the camera? Was the show broadcast in English? Where did you see it (channel and location)?

Comment: I'd also advise you to [register your account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/why-register).

Comment: alright thanks for the tips, I have edited my post with as many of those as i can remember!

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of *[The Ghost Hunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ghost_Hunter_(TV_series))*, a live-action British TV show that aired on kids' channel CBBC between 2000 and 2002. It was based on a series of novels by Ivan Jones.

[image]

The series follows a boy named Roddy Oliver who lives in a present-day English village, and has the ability of "second sight", allowing him to see and hear ghosts. One day, the ghost of a Victorian shoe-shine boy named William Povey appears in his bedroom, asking for Roddy's help in evading the eponymous "Ghost Hunter", Mrs. Croker, who wants to harness William's spectral energy in order to gain immortality.

The series fits most of your criteria, but the plot doesn't quite match up. The ghost is male, not female, and Roddy wasn't trying to put him to rest. I don't remember whether William was ever abused, or whether there was a scene with a carousel (I haven't watched this in 15 years). However, other ghosts did appear in the series and it's possible that you're remembering one of them rather than William.